# Downgrade flutter version to avoid null-safety

Tags: flutter

How can I downgrade the my version of flutter to avoid the null-safety?? I updated and this feature appears but Im using some packages like Badges and https that arent updated for null-safety and Im gettin several bugs to run my code.

My pubspec:
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Thanks!!

Comment: use flutter version manager

Answer (score 3):

In the command line you can downgrade your flutter version with:

- flutter downgrade v1.22.6

This will downgrade your version to the
1.22.6

Comment: Ok!, thanks but what is the lastest version of flutter without null-safety?

Comment: I'm on the latest stable version 1.22.4 and I don't have null safety because null safety is in beta. I think you are might not on the stable channel or you enabled it on the command line. I'm not sure how you can disable once you enable null safetfy.

Comment: I run "flutter pub downgrade" and back to the lastest stable version of dart. Thanks! :D

Comment: Hello @Kurr0 I don't know if you're still able to but could you change your message to "flutter downgrade"? That is the correct command to downgrade the SDK.

Comment: Could not find a command named "version".